# How to get a block out of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code (please open as full page) :

```css
.header_custom{
  background: green;
  color: #FFFFFF
}

#my_block{
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 5px; 
}

#right_side{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 65%;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    #right_side{
        position: static;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .btn{
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="header_custom">HEADER 1</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" selected="">OPTION 1</option>
                            <option value="2">OPTION 2</option>
                            <option value="3">OPTION 3</option>
                            <option value="4">OPTION 4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="header_custom">HEADER 2</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="input1" class="form-control" size="30">
                            <label for="input1">Lorem</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="input2" class="form-control" size="30">
                            <label for="input2">Ipsum</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right_side" class="col-md-6 ">
                        <div id="my_block">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn" disabled="">NEXT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

or https://jsfiddle.net/y0p8w52u/

I want to make the right block responsive. As you can see, it's going outside of the page. I also would like to make it bit wider.

I also tried with

```
#right_side{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using rows and columns, you can rely on them and remove the absolute positioning of `#right_side`.

And I don't quite understand what you want to achieve with the media query rules for `#right_side` so I have removed them from the snippet.

Is this what you are looking for:

```css
.header_custom{
  background: green;
  color: #FFFFFF
}

#my_block{
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 5px; 
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .btn{
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="header_custom">HEADER 1</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" selected="">OPTION 1</option>
                            <option value="2">OPTION 2</option>
                            <option value="3">OPTION 3</option>
                            <option value="4">OPTION 4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="header_custom">HEADER 2</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="input1" class="form-control" size="30">
                            <label for="input1">Lorem</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="input2" class="form-control" size="30">
                            <label for="input2">Ipsum</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right_side" class="col-md-6 ">
                        <div id="my_block">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn" disabled="">NEXT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I want to outbreak the container and stick it on the right edge of the page

Comment: Do you want this effect only when the screen width is smaller than 991px?

Comment: Only on desktop screen

Answer (score 1):

So the magic of boostrap is that you can make your website responsive by setting different widths for your elements based on 12 column grid system. You just set your container, your rows and assign to them different classes(xs for small devices, md for tablets lg for desktop), then you decided how much space do you want them to take. If you want two columns on medium size devices you set col-6-md for both. There is one rule here: 6 + 6 = 12 :) 
Look at below snippet to help you out:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above snippet is from offical Boostrap documentation, which is worth to explore.

I have corrected your code accordingly (I have removed right-side id ;)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
    <form>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="header_custom">HEADER 1</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" selected="">OPTION 1</option>
                            <option value="2">OPTION 2</option>
                            <option value="3">OPTION 3</option>
                            <option value="4">OPTION 4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="header_custom">HEADER 2</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="input1" class="form-control" size="30">
                            <label for="input1">Lorem</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="input2" class="form-control" size="30">
                            <label for="input2">Ipsum</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div id="my_block">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <button type="submit" id="btnCompleteProductConfig" class="btn" disabled="">NEXT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
.header_custom{
  background: green;
  color: #FFFFFF
}

#my_block{
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 5px; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I want to outbreak the container and stick it on the right edge of the page

Comment: Have you checked the code? Container is on the right side of your layout.

Comment: You just need to expand it to the large screen width and you will see it :)

Comment: Well I need to expand it like this https://i.imgur.com/ePOIKX5.png